# Rendering CSS properties at the very end ( Let all other CSS get loaded first )

Tags: css, angular, internet-explorer, kendo-ui

I am working on angular/typescript based SCSS. I have to override some CSS based properties in corresponding SCSS which is the part of the component.

For example Following properties needed to be in effect.

list-view-component.scss

```
.k-grid {
    background-color:rgba(17,255, 238, 0) !important;
}

.k-pager-wrap {
        background-color:rgba(17,255, 238, 0) !important; ---> this doesnt get effect in IE.
}
```

I need to make sure that everything else first loaded and then thense SCSS properties must get apply.
Because at the moment, when I open the UI at chrome these properties get in effect but at IE '.k-pager-wrap' doesn't get effect. Because I saw it's still overriden with another value later on in IE inspection tools. I don't know why.

Can somebody helps me in this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
:host ::ng-deep .k-pager-wrap {
        background-color:rgba(17,255, 238, 0) !important; 
}
```